# Kotlin how to enforce child class from parent class

Tags: class, kotlin, inheritance

This feels super trivial but my google and stack overflow result are filled with completely unrelated stuff.

In java, if an method call returns a parent class object, i.e.

```
ParentClass instance = someCall();
```

You can enforce this to be a child class and call child class specific methods by

```
(ChildClass) instance.doChildClassThings()
```

How does the same work in kotlin?

Comment: What you're doing is called "type casting", or just "casting".

Comment: @Slaw That word was absent from my brain today, but I'm glad Stackoverflow is as fast as usual.

Comment: Are you talking about instance methods, or static methods?  Casting will give an error if the class isn't the correct type, but it won't change which instance method gets called (as those are dispatched dynamically).  But that's not what your Java example is doing, anyway, as without further parens the cast will be applied to the _result_ of the call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `as` keyword to achieve the same functionality as

`(ChildClass) instance.doChildClassThings()`

`instance.doChildClassThings() as ChildClass`

or if `instance` is the ChildClass you are looking for

`(instance as ChildClass).doChildClassThings()`

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html

Comment: Appreciated, my google fu is clearly rusty

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Matt's answer, note that for one common use of casting in Java (maybe even the most common), you *don't* need `as` in Kotlin; namely, if you cast after checking that `instance` actually belongs to `ChildClass`, in Java you write

```java
if (instance instanceof ChildClass) {
    ((ChildClass) instance).doChildClassThings();
}
```

In Kotlin, thanks to [smart-casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#smart-casts), it's sufficient to write

```kotlin
if (instance is ChildClass) {
    instance.doChildClassThings()
}
```

and the compiler inserts the cast.

Comment: Great point, this is a really nice feature in kotlin

Comment: Side note: [JEP 394: Pattern Matching for `instanceof`](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/394) was standardized in Java 16.